# Insert file into SQL db from PHP using the file path

Tags: php, ajax, path, blob

I've a form that insert some values using AJAX, and now
I want to add also an image, but I can't get the image
simply using the superglobal $_FILE['file_name'] in the
PHP code, cause the comunication with PHP is under AJAX.
So I'm wondering if I could load the file from the PHP
using the file's path, infact I could simply pass it 
throught the JS/AJAX.

Or it's a method that permit me to take the whole file
binary code from the JS/AJAX, then pass it to the PHP
and finallu put it in a BLOB of the SQL db?

Ps.: obviously I must use the ajax

Comment: it is difficult to do and convoluted.;

Answer (score 0):

If the file already exists on the server, I think it would be best to just pass the file path to PHP via AJAX and use PHP's `file_get_contents` function to read it in.

If the file does not exist on the server, you're probably better off submitting a form. PHP executing on the server cannot take a file path and get the file from the client.

If you can use jQuery, you could use an HTML form and capture the submit event, [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form into a variable, pass it via AJAX, and return false to prevent the form from submitting (causing a page reload).

---

**EDIT**

On second thought, `serialize` wouldn't be the only part of the solution. That would only get you the value of the file input, not the contents of the file. To get the contents would be much more tedious. It looks like the W3C is working on [something](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), though.

Probably best just to use a standard HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

Currently AJAX does not allow you to upload files.

You just need to use the conventional method.

However, it is a bit possible with Firefox and Chrome. But that method does not work in IE and is rather convoluted.

**EDIT**

Could consider getting Javascript to use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader, serialise it and post that via POST using AJAX. Bit convoluted. FileReader works for Chrome and the latest versions of Firefox. I think it also works for Safari and Opera (but not 100% sure). Probably not for IE.

But it would be a bit complicated at the moment in time to get all browsers to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any expertise regarding uploading files via AJAX. However, if you need help inserting the file into the DB as a BLOB, I can offer some assistance.

Using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), it is fairly easy. They have a page dedicated to details regarding [LOBs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php).

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (image) values (?)");

$fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

$stmt->bindParam(1, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$stmt->execute();
```